# Is it okay to have multiple states in Redux store, handled separatly by combine reducers?

Tags: react-redux

I am reviewing some code in React-Redux app and came across to find out that there are three states in the Redux store and the changes to each state is handled by different reducers(combine reducers). Similar to the following:

src/models

```
--model1
--model2
--model3
```

src/reducers/index.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  model1Reducer,
  model2Reduce,
  model3Reducer
 })
```

src/reducers/model1Reducer

```
// import model1 here
const model1Reducer = (state = model1, action) { }
```

Similarly, the model2Reducer and model3Reducer imports model2 and model3, respectively and act on it.

Is this method of defining three different state trees okay in Redux? One of the principles of Redux is single source of truth. Then how is this okay?

Comment: I am not aware of three distinct states in working with reducers. Can you outline what those are?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described here is the correct way of using redux and is the same as we use it in my organization.

The meaning behind the principle "Single Source of Truth" is for

> make it easy to create universal apps, as the state from your server can be serialized
>   and hydrated into the client with no extra coding effort.

We use combinedReducers to separate part of our app by logic and to avoid a situation where a reducer becomes complex in terms of updating the store. It doesn't mean doing that will separate the store into unrelated states. Each of them is manage independent parts of your store. It "just" make our code more readable, and modular in terms of maintenance.

Here is the part of the Redux docs that explains the concept of [combinedReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#combinereducersreducers)

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing
>   function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of
>   the state.
>
> The combineReducers helper function turns an object whose values are
>   different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can
>   pass to createStore.
>
> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gathers their
>   results into a single state object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rules for reducers:

1. Must return any value besides 'undefined'.
2. Produces 'state' or data to be used inside of your app using only previous state and the action.
3. Must not reach outside of itself to decide what value to return.
4. Must not mutate its input state argument.

Your `combineReducers` will look like this:

```
export default combineReducers({
  property1: model1Reducer,
  property2: model2Reduce,
  property3: model3Reducer
}
```

Your specific reducer will look like this:

```
export default () => {
  return 123;
}
```

Now, what I did not show above is the ES2015 syntax (`selectedSong = null`) where you do something like this:

```
const selectedSongReducer = (selectedSong = null, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SELECTED_SONG') {
    return action.payload;
  }

  return selectedSong;
}
```

This follows rule 1 where we must return any value besides `undefined`, because if we don't we will get undefined when the application boots up, so we implement the Default Argument Values from ES6/ES2015.

It does not have to be defaulted to `null`, it could be an empty array, a string or object, depending on the context of your reducer.

The second time your reducer gets called it will no longer be `undefined`, the first argument will be whatever it returned the last time it was ran.

The only thing that changes when the reducer gets called is the actions object.